The existence of a harmonic diffeomorphism on a punctured surface
Let $\bar{X}$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$, and let $D:=\{p_{1},p_{2},\cdots,p_{n}\}$ be $n$ distinct points on $\bar{X}$. Define $X:=\bar{X}-D$ to be the punctured Riemann surface given by the complement of the divisor $D$. Assume that $2g-2+n>0$, which ensures that the surface $X$ supports a complete hyperbolic metric $h_{0}$.
Let $\sigma$ and $\rho$ be two smooth hyperbolic metrics on the $C^{\infty}$ surface $\bar{X}$. It is known that there exists a unique harmonic diffeomorphism from $(\bar{X},\sigma)$ to $(\bar{X}, \rho)$ in the isotropy class of the identity map $\rm{id}\colon\bar{X}\rightarrow \bar{X}$. This follows from work of Eells and Sampson, Hartman, Schoen and Yau. Moreover, Lohkamp extended this unique existence result to a punctured surface. That is, given a complete hyperbolic metric $h$ on the $C^{\infty}$ surface $X$, there is a unique diffeomorphism $f$, of $X$ homotopic to the identity map, such that $f$ is a harmonic map from $(X,h_{0})$ to $(X,h)$. An alternative proof is provided by
Biswas, Ares-Gastesi and Govindarajan using parabolic Higgs bundle ([1], p.g. 1557). Below is the proof.
Proof. Let $(V, \nabla)$ be the flat rank two vector bundle given by the Fuchsian representation for the Riemann surface $(X,h)$. Let $H$ be the harmonic metric on $V$ given by the main theorem of [2] (p.g. 755 ) for the flat bundle $(V, \nabla)$ on the Riemann surface $(X,h_{0})$. In other words, $H$ gives a section, denoted by $s$, of the associated fiber bundle with fiber ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/{\rm SO}(2)=\mathbb{H}$, where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half plane. This section $s$ gives the harmonic map $f$ mentioned above.
Question: How can we obtain the harmonic map $f$ from the section $s$ ?

I. Biswas, P. Ares-Gastesi and S. Govindarajan,
Parabolic Higgs bundles and Teichmuller spaces for punctured surfaces. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 163 (1972), 261--275.

C. Simpson,
Harmonic bundles on noncompact curves. J. Amer. Math. Soc.
3 (1990), 713--770.



You can get a harmonic map, but you would not know if it is a diffeomorphism (without quoting a suitable uniqueness theorem). Is this what you wanted to know?

In any case, the strongest existence results for harmonic diffeomorphisms are  due to Vlad Markovi'c who proved that every quasiconformal homeomorphism between Riemann surfaces (possibly of infinite type) is homotopic to a harmonic quasiconformal diffeomorphism; the uniqueness in this theorem was known earlier (I think, by Li and Tam).

Thank you for your comment. The section s is a section of a fiber bundle over X whose fibers are isomorphic to the upper half-plane. I would like to know how to obtain a map from X to X using the section s.

I guess you real question is: Given a flat fiber bundle $F\to E\to B$ and a section $s$ of this bundle, how does one obtain an equivariant map from the universal cover of $B$ to the fiber $F$. In your special case, $F$ happens to be the universal cover of $B$ and the holonomy representation $h$ of your flat bundle is discrete and faithful. Can you now put these two things together to get a map $B\to F/h(\pi_1(B))$? By the way, it is a terrible idea to treat Teichmuller space as the space of metrics on a fixed surface. Sadly, some people do this.

Got it, thank you.
